# How to get the message from an Exception from outside the method that generates it?

Tags: java

I have write my Java code with the proper *try{ } catch{ }* blocks for dealing with exceptions, but once the error occurs and the typical message is shown (e.g, through the console), how could I **get** the Exception **message**, Stack trace, or similar text pieces **from outside that method** for further processing it to elaborate a model on how to react to them?

I'm working with multiagent systems and a way of dealing with errors for the agents would be to text-process that kind of messages (Exceptions, etc) to decide about how to behave. But how to access that text if the generating method is returning, let's say, an Integer[]?

Comment: Exceptions is a bad choice for designing application logic. But if you really want to return the exception, then either rethrow it or create a wrapper object for the return value which can contain the integer[] and the list of exceptions.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using exceptions to decide how the agents should behave. That's not what exceptions are for.

Comment: I think that either a) I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, b) you're trying to incorrectly use exceptions as a second return type or c) something like RxJava might help you. Please give an example.

Comment: It's a way of hanling unknown new problems. And emphasize unknown new.

Comment: @shirowww How will you handle known exceptions? Unknown?

Comment: Using Jsoup, for example, instead of returning the desired document, it is generating an exception about 'unexpected end of file from the server' or any other 404 or 50x status code, about not getting your desired document.

Comment: Your program logic shouldn't make decisions based on the exception's detail message. It could vary, for example, according to locale. You should instead catch specific types of exception (subclasses of Exception) and deal accordingly.

Comment: @Tassos Bassoukos You have some waymap for the kind of exceptions you could expect, but for any unknown one, text processing it could be one way of finding a solution.

Comment: To clarify, it could be like a kind of apprenticeship for the agents. You have some preconstructed responses (code) for the known possible exceptions, but for new ones, you could text-preocess them and apply clustering, for example, to discover potential pitfalls of the current agents behaviours, grouping them into mayor kinds.

Answer (score 0):

When using your try{} catch{} statement, the error message shown to the console is shown because of the (i'm guessing) autogenerated method stub such as

```
try{

}catch(Exception e){
     //TODO autogenerated method stub
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the call to "e.printStackTrace()" is what is actually printing to the console.
Instead of having this print to the console, you could instead store this in a variable and perform analysis on it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using exceptions for application logic. If you want to have agents respond to messages, implement a message-queue system. Each agent will have its own message queue that it will inspect to see what messages it has. When messages are processed depends on your agent's lifecycle.

To send messages, you could directly add it to the recipient's message-queue, but a better solution would be to have a dispatcher that accepts a `Message` object that contains the recipient and the message, and then it figures out the correct agent that should receive the message.

You don't have to use a messaging library; you should be able to write a simple one yourself using `Queue<E>`. Be aware of potential concurrency issues if your agents are all running in their own threads.

Answer (score 0):

You could always pervert the use of Exceptions and use something like this:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class ExceptionalOptional<T> {

  @FunctionalInterface
  interface RunnableWithException<T> {
    public T call() throws Exception;
  }

  private final T         value;
  private final Exception exception;

  public ExceptionalOptional(T value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.exception = null;
  }

  public ExceptionalOptional(Exception exception) {
    this.value = null;
    this.exception = exception;
  }

  public static <T> ExceptionalOptional<T> from(T value) {
    return new ExceptionalOptional<T>(value);
  }

  public static <T> ExceptionalOptional<T> from(Exception e) {
    return new ExceptionalOptional<T>(e);
  }

  public static <T> ExceptionalOptional<T> wrap(
      RunnableWithException<T> runnable) {
    try {
      return from(runnable.call());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return from(e);
    }
  }

  public boolean hasValue() {
    return exception == null;
  }

  public boolean hasThrown() {
    return exception != null;
  }

  public T getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public Exception getException() {
    return exception;
  }

  public ExceptionalOptional<T> withValue(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    if (hasValue()) {
      consumer.accept(value);
    }
    return this;
  }

  public ExceptionalOptional<T> onException(Consumer<Exception> consumer) {
    if (hasThrown()) {
      consumer.accept(exception);
    }
    return this;
  }

  public <E extends Exception> ExceptionalOptional<T> onException(
      Consumer<E> consumer, Class<E> klass) {
    if (hasThrown() && klass.isInstance(exception)) {
      consumer.accept(klass.cast(exception));
    }
    return this;
  }
}
```

This allow you to handle your use case in a fluent matter starting off like this:

```
ExceptionalOptional<FileInputStream> fis = 
    wrap(() -> new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt")));
```

I still think what you want to do is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It is not my intention to exceptionally pervert anything. I'm only trying to use the text responses I get from websites or from an unexpected event to make some agents learn to deal with the situation, like we, humans, learn to react to a text message and act consequently, elaborating a model that exploit regularities in the error messages.

Comment: Then what's wrong with `try{..}catch(Exception e){ String foo = e.getMessage();}` ?

Comment: @TB The try{..}catch(Exception e){ String foo = e.getMessage();} could do the job, when saved and treated outside. But I wanted to know if people with greater experience than me know some way of solving this efficiently. Help is always welcome when one is in need.